# how to get items from array on respectively

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an array contain unique keys, these keys I want to take it to get his Data from firebase real-time DB
the array like this

```
["dtnMG3dVEQXL1TPct3awl927jax2", "y5eAQppoEZRELsDL3hLbY5b0A763"]
```

so I iterate it using `forEach` Method to get a single key to check if found in the **users tree** or not But the result is null?

But when I Log the `keys.forEach(key => console.log(key))` I can Get every key in a single line

```
firebase
      .database()
      .ref("users")
      .child(keys.forEach(key => key))
      .once("value")
      .then(users => {
             // let username = users.val().username;
             console.log(users.val());
             // Object.assign(users, { [Object.keys(users)]: username });
       });
```

### Edit

So thats fine and get every single username, Now the new issues is i want to save these names to other object i have

```
users = {
 dtnMG3dVEQXL1TPct3awl927jax2: // the unique key
   -LmUSeyWtBPqcoN8l6fd: [{…}]
   -LmUgcbdzElxWpLkN-F9: [{…}]
    // here's i want to add somthing like thies
   -username : "userOne" //I got it from the Looping
 y5eAQppoEZRELsDL3hLbY5b0A763:
   -LmSTYlxa7bjy0Beazmy: [{…}]
   -LmUad3lvkPdTQDFo4Ds: [{…}]
   -LmUyDmGcEmYKOJnvEiA: [{…}]
    // here's i want to add somthing like thies
   -username : "userTwo" // I got it from the Looping
 }
```

Comment: Try looping first and then make requests to firebase for each key

Comment: I think if I want to loop then save every single key, the final result should be an array of the key so Here we return as we were @RohitKashyap

Comment: Your method is wrong. You **need** to loop through each key in order to make request since child expects a **single** key and not a function.

Comment: yeah I got it, check the last update @RohitKashyap

Comment: Since objects are **unordered** you cannot add properties to a specific location. what you can do is loop through the object and for each one of them add on a property that you want.

Comment: Create a new empty array. Loop through the object and for each element push the username to the empty array.

Comment: Hmm, so you mean I can't use `Object.assign()` to add more property based on key? ***'as you see in the code comment'***  @RohitKashyap

Comment: You can. But not in a specific location as you pointed out. Objects are unordered **key-value** pairs.

Comment: hmm, can you manipulate your answer to achieve these ! @RohitKashyap

Comment: Unfortunately no. You have to come up with your own approach before asking here.

Comment: Mark the answer as the correct one for future references for other users if it helped you. @Oliver D

Answer (score 0):

`.child(keys.forEach(key => key))` - This is your problem. This `forEach` effectively returns all your array values one by one. But you call it inside a function with **one** argument that gets called **one** time. So it will only check for the first value in your array and the rest will be dumped, so its like looking inside a 1-element array.

Solution is to perform the DB calls **inside** the iteration:

```
keys.forEach( key => {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref("users")
      .child(key)
      .once("value")
      .then(users => {
             // let username = users.val().username;
             console.log(users.val());
             // Object.assign(users, { [Object.keys(users)]: username });
       }});
```

EDIT:

to do what you wanted after you edited, assuming the variable `curUser` holds the username you want to insert and `curKey` is the key associated to that username, just: `users[key]["username"] = curUser;`. This will reference the property which is named after curKey in the `users` object, and will create a "username" property in it and store the value there.

Notice that if you already have "username" property in this key object it will be overriden.

** I assumed the data structure of the key-properties inside "users" are objects even tho your code doen't really show it.

Comment: Can you check the Edit section please ! @Gibor

Comment: Excuse me but that's not quite correct. The foreach method always returns undefined. So you are passing undefined to the child function which ofc does not work

Comment: @OliverD is this what you needed?

Comment: Why is always returned undefined? @Fuzzyma

Comment: @DevAS look into the documentation of foreach. This method runs a function on every element of the array and returns undefined. If you want to get something back, there is map or reduce which both return something

Comment: I cannot answer the question. I dont know firebase. I only know that you certainly dont want to pass undefined there

Answer (score 0):

```
keys.forEach(key => key)
```

This return every element of the array `keys`. And you are passing these elements to the `child` function. However, `child` functions expects only one argument.

Try this:

```
for( let key of keys){

    firebase
      .database()
      .ref("users")
      .child(key)
      .once("value")
      .then(users => {
            // let username = users.val().username;
       console.log(users.val());
            // Object.assign(users, { [Object.keys(users)]: username });
      });

}
```

**Side not: Do not call `async` function inside `forEach` loop.**

Comment: Can you check the Edit section please ! @user9408899

Comment: @OliverD ask another question for it. Because It is not directly related with this one.